# TSQL - Filter group if it contains all null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I would like to filter out the group which contains all null values for TASK_START & TASK_END which will be B and D.

Sample Table Data

```
+----+-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| ID | STATE |       ENTER_STATE       |       LEAVE_STATE       |       TASK_START        |        TASK_END         |
+----+-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| A  | UP    | 2018-11-11 08:00:00.000 | 2018-11-11 08:30:00.000 | 2018-11-11 08:00:00.000 | 2018-11-11 08:10:00.000 |
| A  | UP    | 2018-11-11 09:00:00.000 | 2018-11-11 09:30:00.000 | NULL                    | NULL                    |
| A  | UP    | 2018-11-11 10:00:00.000 | 2018-11-11 10:30:00.000 | 2018-11-11 08:20:00.000 | 2018-11-11 08:30:00.000 |
| B  | UP    | 2018-11-11 08:00:00.000 | 2018-11-11 09:00:00.000 | NULL                    | NULL                    |
| B  | UP    | 2018-11-11 09:00:00.000 | 2018-11-11 10:00:00.000 | NULL                    | NULL                    |
| B  | UP    | 2018-11-11 10:20:00.000 | 2018-11-11 11:00:00.000 | NULL                    | NULL                    |
| B  | UP    | 2018-11-11 11:00:00.000 | 2018-11-11 12:00:00.000 | NULL                    | NULL                    |
| C  | UP    | 2018-11-11 08:00:00.000 | 2018-11-11 08:20:00.000 | 2018-11-11 08:15:00.000 | 2018-11-11 08:30:00.000 |
| C  | UP    | 2018-11-11 08:20:00.000 | 2018-11-11 08:30:00.000 | 2018-11-11 08:20:00.000 | 2018-11-11 08:35:00.000 |
| D  | UP    | 2018-11-11 08:00:00.000 | 2018-11-11 08:10:00.000 | NULL                    | NULL                    |
| D  | UP    | 2018-11-11 08:10:00.000 | 2018-11-11 09:10:00.000 | NULL                    | NULL                    |
+----+-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [ID] CHAR(1)
   ,[STATE] CHAR(2)
   ,[ENTER_STATE] DATETIME2(0)
   ,[LEAVE_STATE] DATETIME2(0)
   ,[TASK_START] DATETIME2(0)
   ,[TASK_END] DATETIME2(0)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource
VALUES ('A', 'UP', '2018-11-11 08:00:00.000', '2018-11-11 08:30:00.000', '2018-11-11 08:00:00.000', '2018-11-11 08:10:00.000')
      ,('A', 'UP', '2018-11-11 09:00:00.000', '2018-11-11 09:30:00.000', NULL, NULL)
      ,('A', 'UP', '2018-11-11 10:00:00.000', '2018-11-11 10:30:00.000', '2018-11-11 08:20:00.000', '2018-11-11 08:30:00.000')
      ,('B', 'UP', '2018-11-11 08:00:00.000', '2018-11-11 09:00:00.000', NULL, NULL)
      ,('B', 'UP', '2018-11-11 09:00:00.000', '2018-11-11 10:00:00.000', NULL, NULL)
      ,('B', 'UP', '2018-11-11 10:20:00.000', '2018-11-11 11:00:00.000', NULL, NULL)
      ,('B', 'UP', '2018-11-11 11:00:00.000', '2018-11-11 12:00:00.000', NULL, NULL)
      ,('C', 'UP', '2018-11-11 08:00:00.000', '2018-11-11 08:20:00.000', '2018-11-11 08:15:00.000', '2018-11-11 08:30:00.000')
      ,('C', 'UP', '2018-11-11 08:20:00.000', '2018-11-11 08:30:00.000', '2018-11-11 08:20:00.000', '2018-11-11 08:35:00.000')
      ,('D', 'UP', '2018-11-11 08:00:00.000', '2018-11-11 08:10:00.000', NULL, NULL)
      ,('D', 'UP', '2018-11-11 08:10:00.000', '2018-11-11 09:10:00.000', NULL, NULL);

WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT *
         ,MAX([TASK_START]) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID]) AS [DateStart]
         ,MAX([TASK_END]) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID]) AS [DateEnd]
    FROM @DataSource
)
SELECT *
FROM DataSource
WHERE NOT ([DateStart] IS NULL AND [DateEnd] IS NULL);
```

[image]

The idea is to get the maximum(or minimum if you like) date for each group and then, if there are rows where this value is `NULL` to exclude them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `not exists` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1 
                  from table t1 
                  where t1.id = t.id and t1.task_start is not null and t1.task_end is not null
                 );
```

Other option would to use `GROUP BY`  :

```
select id
from table t
group by id
having sum(case when task_start is not null then 1 else 0  end) = 0 and
       sum(case when task_end is not null then 1 else 0  end) = 0;
```

Comment: Wouldn't that remove the field from A too?

Comment: @Kyrive. . .Yes it would remove `A` as because `TASK_START` & `TASK_END` is not null.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use `count()` with `having`:

```
select id
from table t
group by id
having count(task_start) = 0 and
       count(task_end) = 0;
```